# Hibernate: possible to get a specific value as String using join, or does it require the whole object to be joined?

Tags: java, hibernate

Say I have

```
class Agent {
     private String a;
     private String b;
     private String c;
     //other values
}

class Bandit {
     private String a;
     private String b;
     private String c;
     private String d;
     //other values
}
```

And I would like to join the D value in class A. 
Now I was wondering whether it was possible to do this using a `JoinFormula`
With something along the lines of:

```
    @JoinFormula(value="select bandit.d from Bandit bandit where bandit.a = a, bandit.b = b, bandit.c = c")
    Private string d; //<== extra transient variable in Agent
```

Or would a better way be to use `@Formula`?

The issue I'm facing is that both of those only seem intended for mapped objects, whilst I don't want to retrieve the whole object, just join a single value. 
The class\variable names are just dummies so don't get too fussed over the unlogical join of Agents and Bandits.